# Conditional for wordpress WP_Query class' "orderby" or "order" arguments

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Context: using Ajax with Wordpress.

`functions.php`:

```
       $filterby = $_POST['filter'];
        $orderby = $_POST['order'];
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'projects',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            // 'orderby' => $orderby,
            'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC' ),
            // 'order' => 'ASC',
            'category_name' => $filterby,
        );
```

`$filterby` regards post categories.

`$orderby` can be `'date'` or `'title'`, depending on what the users choose.

If it is `'date'`, I want ``order' => 'DESC'. [displays latest posts first]

If it is `'title'`, I want ``order' => 'ASC'. [displays alphabetically, from a to z]

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I'm not totally following your question. Are you asking how to write the query? Or are you asking how to re-order the list in the browser without refreshing the page? When you say you're using Ajax - how exactly are you employing it in relation to this issue?

Comment: Please update your question with what your need. This Question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, and yes I'm asking how I can write the query so that when the user, on clicking either button on the front-end, can order the posts by title (a to z) or by date (latest first). I found the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

simply use if statement for check

```
$filterby = $_POST['filter'];
$orderby = $_POST['order'];
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => $filterby
];
if($orderby == 'date'){
    $args['orderby'] = 'date'; 
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
}elseif($orderby == 'title'){
    $args['orderby'] = 'title';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
}else{
    unset($args['order']); unset($args['orderby']);
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $date_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'category_name' => $filterby,
    );
    $title_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'category_name' => $filterby,
    );

 if ( $_POST['order'] == date ) {
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $date_args );
 } elseif ( $_POST['order'] == title ) {
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $title_args );
        }
```